# Replace all occurrences of the dot character with an underscore character in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

In JavaScript, I need to replace all occurrences of the dot character (.) with the underscore character (_) if any EXCEPT the last one.

This expression replaces ALL occurrences of the dot character (.) including the last one with an underscore character (_) but I'm trying to figure out how to change this so it leaves the last (.) character alone.

```
str.replace(/\./g, '_');
```

Thanks !!

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fun with [look aheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
"12.34.56.78".replace(/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/g,"_")
```

Comment: I tested and your expression works perfectly - can I impose on you to ask how it works ? I mean, I think this part (?=[^.]*\.) is what creates the exception - but would like to understand the syntax so I know why it works. Thanks very much !!

Comment: Read this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html Basic idea is the look ahead makes a match and does hot include it in the final result.

Comment: Many thanks - I tested and it works, Avinash's answer (below) doesn't work if there are characters following the last dot character, but your solution does. Thanks very much and thanks to all !

Comment: This works perfectly, but I think `"12.34.56.78".replace(/\.(?=.*\.[^.]*$)/g,"_")` is more correct.

Comment: Yes, this works too, just as espascarello's solution does. I looked at the link that espascarello mentioned for the explanation as to how it works but I'm a sad case and don't understand - if you have a minute and can explain how what's contained in the () creates an exception (so the last . is left alone) that would be great - thanks !

Comment: Well I also saw this kind of expression first time, but as I understand `\.(?=.*\.[^.]*$)` is dot `\.` which is followed with (now going after `?=`) anything `.*` and dot `\.` and anything but dot `[^.]*` and end of string `$`.

Comment: Visualization of the regular expression. [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5C.(%3F%3D%5B%5E.%5D*%5C.)%2Fg) In plain English it says "Find a period that has other characters [optional] and a period in following it."

Answer (score 1):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html),

```
> "12.34.56.78".replace(/\.(?![^.]*$)/g,"_")
'12_34_56.78'
> "12.34.56.78.".replace(/\.(?![^.]*$)/g,"_")
'12_34_56_78.'
```

Comment: Your definition of "last dot" is a bit odd.

Comment: Like the text pattern I used that you copied and added the . to the end. It should match anywhere, not just the last character.

Comment: Yours is "the last character of the string if it is a dot", but it should be "the last *dot character* even if not at the end of the string"

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes :-)